# changing model's id type from integer to decimal makes all entries try to be 0.0 (rails 3.2.1)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, primary-key, duplicates

I'm a rails beginner (I think I have the basics down pretty well at this point), and I'm working on an app with a simple parent-child structure: Company => Client => Group => Order. The relevant DB tables for this question are Group and Order (Group has_many Orders).

Right now, when I create a new group, one of the text fields on the form is 'Order Quantity' (which is a :size attribute in the Group model), and there is a line of code in the Create action for GroupsController that generates *n* blank orders that belong to that particular group:

```
  if @group.save
    @group.size.times do
      Order.create(:group_id => @group.id)
    end
```

This works fine, but I want Order.id to be a decimal number rather than an integer. I tried generating the following migration:

```
class ChangeOrderIdToDecimal < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :orders, :id, :decimal, :precision => 5, :scale => 4
  end
```

which, at first, seemed to do what I wanted. All the existing orders changed from 4, 5, 6 to 4.0, 5.0, 6.0. What I ultimately want to do, though, is to add some code to the Create action in GroupsController like this:

```
  if @group.save
    order_id_decimal = 0.001
    @group.size.times do
      order_id = "#{@group.id}.#{order_id_decimal}".to_f
      Order.create(:group_id => @group.id, :id => order_id)
      order_id_decimal += 0.001
    end
```

The idea being, if the Group ID was 75, then the orders in that Group would have ID's 75.001, 75.002, 75.003, etc.

For some reason, though, when I create new groups, it tries to save every order id as 0.0000 and gives me this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in GroupsController#create

Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '0.0000' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `orders`
(`created_at`, `group_id`, `note`, `order_status`, `title`, `updated_at`, ) VALUES 
('2012-03-04 20:28:15', 20, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-03-04 20:28:15')
```

I've tried manually changing an Order's ID from the rails console, and it saves without giving me errors, but it doesn't *actually* save. If I type Order.find(0.0) it pulls up the one order I just changed and it has 0.0 for ID. I'm completely baffled by this, and I haven't been able to find any help from googling it. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to encapsulate business logic in the ID field. This is a big no-no from an application design perspective, and having an ID field that isn't an integer is a big no-no from a database design perspective.

I would give up on this notion that you want the IDs to be somehow correlated across tables; foreign keys and join tables should be able to accomplish the end goal (of relating groups and orders). Primary keys are not intended for business logic and should not be used for that: don't care about the contents of your ID fields and your application will be a lot happier.

Comment: Huh. Well it's good to know that what I'm trying is outside the scope of normal conventions (I had kind of guessed this was the case), but I'd still like to understand what's going on and why I can't save the order ID as anything other than 0.0. The end result is not relating groups and orders, I've already done that. having the order ID be an extension of the Group ID is going to be a functional part of my application in terms of its UI, but I guess I'll start exploring other ways of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: After giving it some more thought I see the sense in what you're saying. What I ended up doing was adding a new column to the Orders table called "order_id" which lets me generate the front-facing ID using the procedure I described in my post. It seems like an unnecessary extra db column, which I think is why I didn't think to try that first. But you're right, my application is a lot happier with this arrangement, and it does exactly what I need it to. Thanks again for taking the time to answer.

Comment: My pleasure! If you liked my answer approve it; then more people will respond positively to your questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm new to stack overflow as well. Approved!

Answer (score 0):

Use ONLY integer type for id field and you will NEVER have problems like this. If you have changed type for id you should manage it manually